# How to stop image referring back to the parent folder

Tags: php, html

Please I've been trying my best to get this working but I can't figure it out. This is the code:

```
$image = $p['Photo']; ` <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("http://myurl.com/$image"); ?>" />`
```

Each time it runs, it shows **http://myurl.com/../postphotos/image.png**
as the output instead of **http://myurl.com/postphotos/image.png**

Note: post photos are the actual folder where the images are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$image = preg_replace('/^\.+\//', '', $p['Photo']);
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("http://uamxtreme.com/$image"); ?>" />
```

Comment: Bro... You are an angel..... I have been here over the past 12 hours on pc

Comment: I even feel like crying now

Answer (score 0):

Where and how `$p['Photo'];` generated?

But any way you can do this:

```
$image = str_replace ("../", "", $p['Photo']);
```

Comment: from mysql database

Comment: better solution is to fix the path of image when it writes into mysql

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
$image = $p['Photo'];
$image = str_replace('../', '', $image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without enough code it's impossible to help but my "guess" would be that it's got something to do with the `$p` variable check if that by any chance set to a path if it is maybe you should remove the `"../"`

That's the best I can give you Otherwise it's possible to have something to do with $image or another variable or function or something but without any further detail that is all I can give you.